# Read bytes from int to write Unicode C

Tags: c, unicode, bit-manipulation

In short, I'm trying to get these `{0xe2, 0x98, 0xba}` from `int c = L'☺';` without any libraries except `unistd`.

I know it has to do with bit masks and what not but after a few hours of getting nowhere I need a hand.

Thanks!

Comment: The value you're trying to get is UTF-8. You will need to convert it.

Comment: Don't roll this yourself. People who have spent way more time than is healthy on the "how to read in/write out unicode" problem (which is a *hugely* complex subject) wrote excellent libraries to do this for you.

Comment: On what operating system (and version) and compiler (and version) and compilation flags?

Comment: "after a few hours of getting nowhere" --> posting what you have done/tied would improve this post.

Comment: I can't use any external libraries  @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: @NoahCardoza that... makes no sense whatsoever. Of course you can. You just link them in.

Comment: I think we're looking at stupid professor tricks here. Ask the professor for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Read bytes from int to write Unicode C
>   I'm trying to get these {0xe2, 0x98, 0xba} from `int c = L'☺';`

If code can start from a *UTF−8 string literal*, suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s = u8"☺";
  printf("0x%02hhx 0x%02hhx 0x%02hhx\n", s[0], s[1], s[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0xe2 0x98 0xba
```

To make an integer, use a wide enough integer type like `uint32_t` and the values `s[0], s[1], s[2]`

Answer (score 1):

Use some UTF-8/Unicode library, such as [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/); many libraries have UTF8 related functions, e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html). C11 has *some* [multibyte character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte) support (so check that your implementation uses UTF8...)

Read more about [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) including **http://utf8everywhere.org/**

Perhaps your OS or C implementations provide something.

UTF-8 & Unicode are complex (with delicate corner cases); so avoid reinventing the wheel and trying to make some function by yourself.

Probably `L'☺'` means something different on Windows and Linux (e.g. because `sizeof(wchar_t)` can be different; it could be 16 or 32 bits). And your C source file can be UTF8 encoded (this is *often* the case) but might not be, so what exactly is `L'☺'` in your source code is debatable.

<sup>(in  theory the source code might not be UTF8)</sup>

For safety, better stick to UTF-8, assume and document that both the C source file and the implementation uses UTF-8, so use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), without any `wchar_t` or `L'☺'`, and have a `"\342\230\272"` string (instead of `"☺"`), perhaps mentioning in a *comment* that it is `/*U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE  ☺*/`; or at least use a string `"☺"` but avoid wide chars.

In other words, I heard that a source code containing `L'☺'` is not portable between Windows and Linux (but I don't care since I never used Windows). So for portability reasons prefer at least using literal strings like `"☺"` (but `"\342\230\272"` is even better) and explicitly document what encoding (preferably UTF-8) is used in both your source code and your application's input and output.

[Character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) can become a nightmare. You'll find libraries such as  [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to deal with that. But in 2017 use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) (both in your C source code and in the output of your program) hence avoid `L'☺'` in  your source code.

Comment: Or, depending on what OS he's using, there's probably some pretty decent Unicode functionality included with the system APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C11 compiler, it has a standard header  with unicode support.  You want the routine c32rtomb:

```
#include <uchar.h>

char buffer[4];
len = c32rtomb(buffer, L'☺', 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure that *every* C11 implementation uses Unicode or UTF8? (what about EBCDIC-based ones). AFAIK some C implementations have 32 bits `char`-s and standards allow that

Comment: It is part of the C11 standard.   Of course, many C compilers still don't implement C99 properly, let alone C11.

Comment: What is part of the standard? `c32rtomb` or UTF8? And what about implementations with wider than 8 bits `char`-s? (I'm pretty sure the standard allows that, even if I don't know many implementations doing that). Also `wchar_t` has various sizes on different implementations (and that is why it is not very useful)

Comment: uchar.h and c32rtomb are part of the standard

Comment: But please cite where is UTF8 or Unicode mentioned. IIRC it is not that simple! (since 16 bits or 32 bits `char`-s are possible)

Comment: Section 7.28 says <uchar.h> defines "types and functions for manipulating Unicode characters."  It never mentions "UTF8" specifically, just Unicode multibyte character encodings.  As far as I'm aware, UTF8 is the only byte-oriented Unicode encoding defined by the Unicode consortium.

Comment: Sorry this won't work, I can only use the `unistd.h` library.